# Unable to use IdentityManager API from Postman

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture

I am using postman and I am trying to get the users list from identity Manager. But I am unable to configure the app correctly. I try to get the users from https://localhost/idm/api/users

I get the token with the API+idmgr+openid scopes and I have the Administrator role in my claims.

Here is the startup file:

```
namespace WebHost
{
    internal class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new NLogLogProvider());

            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MembershipRebootConnection"];

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "oidc",
                Authority = "https://localhost/ids",
                ClientId = "postman",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                Scope = "openid idmgr",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Jwt",
                Notifications = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                    {
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });

            X509Certificate2 cert = Certificate.Get();

            app.Map("/idm", adminApp =>
            {
                app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AllowedAudiences = new string[] { "https://localhost/ids" + "/resources" },
                    AuthenticationType = "Jwt",
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new[] {
                        new X509CertificateSecurityTokenProvider("https://localhost/ids", cert)
                    },
                    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active
                });

                var factory = new IdentityManagerServiceFactory();
                factory.Configure(connectionString);

                var securityConfig = new ExternalBearerTokenConfiguration
                {
                    Audience = "https://localhost/ids" + "/resources",
                    BearerAuthenticationType = "Jwt",
                    Issuer = "https://localhost/ids",
                    SigningCert = cert,
                    Scope = "openid idmgr",
                    RequireSsl = true,
                };

                adminApp.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerOptions()
                {
                    Factory = factory,
                    SecurityConfiguration = securityConfig
                });
            });

            app.Map(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerSuffix"], core =>
            {
                IdentityServerServiceFactory idSvrFactory = Factory.Configure();
                idSvrFactory.ConfigureCustomUserService(connectionString);

                var options = new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    SiteName = "Login",

                    SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
                    Factory = idSvrFactory,
                    EnableWelcomePage = true,
                    RequireSsl = true
                };

                core.UseIdentityServer(options);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who may want to know how I did it, well I made a lot of search about Owin stuff and how Identity Server works and find out my problem was not that far.

I removed the JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap 
I removed the UseOpenId stuff (don't remove it if you are using an openId external login provider (if you are using google, facebook or twitter, there is classes for that, just install the nuget, it's pretty straight forward)

This section let you **configure** the **bearer token** which is the default type token i used in my app(I decided to use **password authentication** to simplify Postman request to do automatic testing but I still user **Code authentication** in my apps)

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorityUrl"],
                ValidationMode = ValidationMode.ValidationEndpoint,
                RequiredScopes = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiScope"] }
            });
```

I have disabled the IdentityManagerUi interface as I was planning to use the API

```
 app.Map(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityManagerSuffix"].ToString(), idmm =>
            {
                var factory = new IdentityManagerServiceFactory();
                factory.Configure(connectionString);

                idmm.UseIdentityManager(new IdentityManagerOptions()
                {
                    DisableUserInterface = true,
                    Factory = factory,
                    SecurityConfiguration = new HostSecurityConfiguration()
                    {
                        HostAuthenticationType = Constants.BearerAuthenticationType
                    }
                });
            });
```

And I configure the Identity Server like this:

```
app.Map(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerSuffix"], core =>
            {
                IdentityServerServiceFactory idSvrFactory = Factory.Configure();
                idSvrFactory.ConfigureCustomUserService(connectionString);

                var options = new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    SiteName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteName"],

                    SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
                    Factory = idSvrFactory,
                    EnableWelcomePage = true,
                    RequireSsl = true,
                };

                core.UseIdentityServer(options);
            });
```

In IdentityServerServiceFactory I call this chunk of code:

```
var clientStore = new InMemoryClientStore(Clients.Get());
```

And the code for the Client should be something like:

```
public static Client Get()
        {
            return new Client
            {
                ClientName = "PostMan Application",
                ClientId = "postman",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
                        new Secret("ClientSecret".Sha256())
                    },
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("name", "Identity Manager API"),
                        new Claim("role", IdentityManager.Constants.AdminRoleName),
                    },
                **Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner**, //Password authentication
                PrefixClientClaims = false,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                ClientUri = "https://www.getpostman.com/",
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                    {
                        "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback",
                        //aproulx - 2015-11-24 -ADDED This line, url has changed on the postman side
                        "https://app.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
                    },

                //IdentityProviderRestrictions = new List<string>(){Constants.PrimaryAuthenticationType},
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "postman",
                        "IdentityManager",
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiScope"],
                        Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityManager.Constants.IdMgrScope,
                    }
            };
        }
```

On the postman side just do:

```
POST /ids/connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: local-login.net
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 33e98423-701f-c615-8b7a-66814968ba1a
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=postman&client_secret=SecretPassword&grant_type=password&scope=APISTUFF&username=apiViewer&password=ICanUseTheApi
```

Hope that it will help somebody

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the solution. 
Is there, by any chance, a github sample project for the above ?

Comment: Sadly no, I could work something out if you want! Just let me know

Comment: That would be helpful for lots of people.

Comment: Hello, can you kindly prepare a working demo ... I have followed your instructions be honestly, got lost.

Answer (score 0):

Shaer,

I saw your comment and because of that I've created a [project](https://github.com/danielboterocorrea/IdentityManagerMyVersion/tree/PostmanExample) (make sure you clone the postmanexample branch) where you can see a working example related to Alegrowin's post. The idea is use postman to access the IdentityManager Api.

**Steps**

- Open postman and choose the POST verb
- Put this as url: https://localhost:44337/ids/connect/token
- In header put key = Content-Type and value = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- In the body, choose raw and paste this client_id=postman&client_secret=ClientSecret&grant_type=password&scope=idmgr&username=admin&password=admin
- Hit send

After this you are going to receive something like this

```
{"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImEzck1VZ01Gdjl0UGNsTGE2eUYzekFrZnF1RSIsImtpZCI6ImEzck1VZ01Gdjl0UGNsTGE2eUYzekFrZnF1RSJ9.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJwb3N0bWFuIiwic2NvcGUiOiJpZG1nciIsInN1YiI6Ijk1MWE5NjVmLTFmODQtNDM2MC05MGU0LTNmNmRlYWM3YjliYyIsImFtciI6WyJwYXNzd29yZCJdLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MDU1ODg1MTgsImlkcCI6Imlkc3J2IiwibmFtZSI6IkFkbWluIiwicm9sZSI6IklkZW50aXR5TWFuYWdlckFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDMzNy9pZHMiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDMzNy9pZHMvcmVzb3VyY2VzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1NTkyMTE4LCJuYmYiOjE1MDU1ODg1MTh9.h0KjlnKy3Ml-SnZg6cYSPJW4XxsOFxDB8K9JY4Zx_I1KbMQxctjkDrTVfSylfjFXlwpyBD-qqfxmRkOKsz_6zSZneaJpyWsJt2FTqCNOWJJV9BdPbViWcM_vADFkVpwiiSaTCv7k08xwj8StGCq5zlYLU68k8awYpXzgpz0O8zPZpfc0oSN3ZQJVFEKBfE4ATbPo6ut2i0_Y3lPbQiwjXJgA_wwp-W0L3zY8A5rfYSwKU0KzS51BKBSn6svBCjTu84Dm2KM-zlManMar1Ybjoy108Xvuliq_zBNdbeEt-Daau_RNrasw1tya_cZicK85IB1TJdUSKPGwNG5xEirNzg",
"expires_in": 3600,
"token_type": "Bearer"}
```

- Copy the access token and create a GET request
- Put this as url: https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users?count=10&start=0
- Into the headers put key = Authorization and value = Bearer [paste the token]

Example

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImEzck1VZ01Gdjl0UGNsTGE2eUYzekFrZnF1RSIsImtpZCI6ImEzck1VZ01Gdjl0UGNsTGE2eUYzekFrZnF1RSJ9.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJwb3N0bWFuIiwic2NvcGUiOiJpZG1nciIsInN1YiI6Ijk1MWE5NjVmLTFmODQtNDM2MC05MGU0LTNmNmRlYWM3YjliYyIsImFtciI6WyJwYXNzd29yZCJdLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MDU1ODg1MTgsImlkcCI6Imlkc3J2IiwibmFtZSI6IkFkbWluIiwicm9sZSI6IklkZW50aXR5TWFuYWdlckFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDMzNy9pZHMiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDMzNy9pZHMvcmVzb3VyY2VzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1NTkyMTE4LCJuYmYiOjE1MDU1ODg1MTh9.h0KjlnKy3Ml-SnZg6cYSPJW4XxsOFxDB8K9JY4Zx_I1KbMQxctjkDrTVfSylfjFXlwpyBD-qqfxmRkOKsz_6zSZneaJpyWsJt2FTqCNOWJJV9BdPbViWcM_vADFkVpwiiSaTCv7k08xwj8StGCq5zlYLU68k8awYpXzgpz0O8zPZpfc0oSN3ZQJVFEKBfE4ATbPo6ut2i0_Y3lPbQiwjXJgA_wwp-W0L3zY8A5rfYSwKU0KzS51BKBSn6svBCjTu84Dm2KM-zlManMar1Ybjoy108Xvuliq_zBNdbeEt-Daau_RNrasw1tya_cZicK85IB1TJdUSKPGwNG5xEirNzg
```

- Hit send

You should receive something like this

```
{
"data": {
    "items": [
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "081d965f-1f84-4360-90e4-8f6deac7b9bc",
                "username": "alice",
                "name": "Alice Smith"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/081d965f-1f84-4360-90e4-8f6deac7b9bc",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/081d965f-1f84-4360-90e4-8f6deac7b9bc"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "5f292677-d3d2-4bf9-a6f8-e982d08e1306",
                "username": "bob",
                "name": "Bob Smith"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/5f292677-d3d2-4bf9-a6f8-e982d08e1306",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/5f292677-d3d2-4bf9-a6f8-e982d08e1306"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "e3c7fd2b-3942-456f-8871-62e64c351e8c",
                "username": "xoetuvm",
                "name": "Uylocms Xcyfhpc"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/e3c7fd2b-3942-456f-8871-62e64c351e8c",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/e3c7fd2b-3942-456f-8871-62e64c351e8c"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "0777d8de-91be-41e2-82ae-01c4576c7aca",
                "username": "xdbktbb",
                "name": "Qbcqwrg Mypxduu"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/0777d8de-91be-41e2-82ae-01c4576c7aca",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/0777d8de-91be-41e2-82ae-01c4576c7aca"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "10d2760a-2b3f-4912-af2a-2bcd9d113af9",
                "username": "acrkkzf",
                "name": "Qcmwcha Kdibtke"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/10d2760a-2b3f-4912-af2a-2bcd9d113af9",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/10d2760a-2b3f-4912-af2a-2bcd9d113af9"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "5e16f086-a487-4429-b2a6-b05a739e1e71",
                "username": "wjxfulk",
                "name": "Eihevix Bjzjbwz"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/5e16f086-a487-4429-b2a6-b05a739e1e71",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/5e16f086-a487-4429-b2a6-b05a739e1e71"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "256e23de-410a-461d-92cc-55684de8be6f",
                "username": "zputkfb",
                "name": "Vhwjjpd Stfpoum"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/256e23de-410a-461d-92cc-55684de8be6f",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/256e23de-410a-461d-92cc-55684de8be6f"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "725cc088-96c3-490d-bc66-a376c8ca34ff",
                "username": "teshydj",
                "name": "Tirsnex Tdlkfii"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/725cc088-96c3-490d-bc66-a376c8ca34ff",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/725cc088-96c3-490d-bc66-a376c8ca34ff"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "ac773092-e3db-4711-9c95-a2a57c1ff25f",
                "username": "blulsuj",
                "name": "Puuncng Lbmlcsb"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/ac773092-e3db-4711-9c95-a2a57c1ff25f",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/ac773092-e3db-4711-9c95-a2a57c1ff25f"
            }
        },
        {
            "data": {
                "subject": "81f878b1-016e-4fea-9929-54e3b1d55cce",
                "username": "yeqwlfy",
                "name": "Qtfimdr Sxvgizd"
            },
            "links": {
                "detail": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/81f878b1-016e-4fea-9929-54e3b1d55cce",
                "delete": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users/81f878b1-016e-4fea-9929-54e3b1d55cce"
            }
        }
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "count": 10,
    "total": 18806,
    "filter": null
},
"links": {
    "create": {
        "href": "https://localhost:44337/idm/api/users",
        "meta": [
            {
                "type": "username",
                "name": "Username",
                "dataType": 0,
                "required": true
            },
            {
                "type": "password",
                "name": "Password",
                "dataType": 1,
                "required": true
            },
            {
                "type": "name",
                "name": "Name",
                "dataType": 0,
                "required": true
            },
            {
                "type": "Age",
                "name": "Age",
                "dataType": 4,
                "required": true
            },
            {
                "type": "IsNice",
                "name": "IsNice",
                "dataType": 5,
                "required": true
            },
            {
                "type": "role.admin",
                "name": "Is Administrator",
                "dataType": 5,
                "required": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Kind regards
Daniel